# Writing multiple seperate numpy arrays to a single comma delimited text file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to take multiple numpy arrays and write them to a text file that is comma delimited.  Here is the example of my original data and the final data that I am trying to produce:

```
array([[1., 3., 0., 1.],
       [2., 5., 3., 1.]].....
```

and so forth.  For multiple different arrays of four-column lengths.  I can get an out put txt file using write() but I can't get the data into the format shown below:

```
1., 3., 0., 1.
2., 5., 3., 1.
```

Also, I need to have the 0th column integers and the 1st through 3rd be floating point.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
data = array([[1., 3., 0., 1.],
              [2., 5., 3., 1.]].....

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for x in data:
        f.write('%d,%f,%f,%f\n' % tuple(x))
```

This outputs

```
1,3.000000,0.000000,1.000000
2,5.000000,3.000000,1.000000
```

You can adjust the precision of the floating point output by changing `%f` to `%.2f` if you want two decimal places, for instance.

Comment: @JonClements I assumed the `.`'s referred to the fact that the values are floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pandas for this:

```
import numpy
import pandas
data = numpy.array([[1., 3., 0., 1.],
   [2., 5., 3., 1.]])
data = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b','c','d'])
data['a'] = data['a'].astype(int)
data.to_csv('outfile.csv')
```